# How to translate this sql to left join without subquery？

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to create a view in mysql.But that in mysql does't support subquery.
How to write the sql without subquery?

```
select * from dev_location t1

        inner join 

    (
        select
            `dev_location`.`device_id` AS `device_id`,
            max(`dev_location`.`id`) AS `id`
        from
            `dev_location`
        group by `dev_location`.`device_id`) t2

    on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL views don't support subqueries in the `from` clause.  The following should work in a view:

```
select dl.*
from dev_location dl
where not exists (select 1
                  from dev_location dl2
                  where dl2.device_id = dl.device_id and
                        dl2.id > dl.id
                 );
```

This reformulates the query to say:  "Get me all the rows from `dev_location` where the `device_id` has no greater `id`."  This is an awkward way of getting the max.

And, with an index on `dev_location(device_id, id)`, it might perform better than your version.